# front-end and frontend, tags that could be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, exact-duplicates

When creating my latest question, I found that there were two tags that look to mean the same thing. Any way a synonym could be created?

Answer (score 4):

Merged........................

Comment: You my friend are fast :)

Comment: @Bainternet so fast system made me solve captcha to post this answer. :)

Comment: Then slow down and leave some for the rest of us :)